# Doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, transition-matrix, stochastic-matrices

> Prove that Markov chain will be irreducible if its transition matrix is doubly stochastic.

---

I was told to use Birkhoff's theorem, but I don't know how to use it at all.

Comment: And what does doubly stochastic mean for you? I know a little bit about the theory here and I’ve never come across the term

Comment: This isn't true.  Consider $S_n$ the group of (standard representation of) permutation matrices.  They are all doubly stochastic and numerous ones are reducible -- e.g. every single involution (order at most 2 permutation) for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Indeed. When the transition matrix is the identity matrix it is clear that every point in the state space constitutes an equivalence class. I.e. every point communicates only with itself since that chain does not "move".

Comment: The Perron-Frobenius theorem (which is very related to Birkhoff's theorem) can be used to show that for any nonnegative, irreducible, matrix $M$, there exists diagonal matrices $D,D'$ such that $DMD'$ is double stochastic.

Comment: @user8675309 Your example is not an irreducible matrix.

Comment: @KurtG. Yours isn't as well.

Comment: @Surb . The  identity matrix is clearly not [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducibility_(mathematics)) but it is doubly stochastic (bi stochastic). OP asked about irreducible Markov chains when the transition matrix is bi stochastic. Plus there are several [Birkhoff theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem),

Comment: fair enough @KurtG.

Comment: @Surb -- as I said, I gave a bunch of examples of *reducible* matrices which contradict OP's assertion.  Kurt followed up in the same vein.